# Meaning of "giving the fellow a charge to run" and "contrived to send a Turk" in 1720

Tags: meaning, idioms, literature

I'm having trouble understanding two phrases from Daniel Defoe's [*The Life, Adventures, & Piracies of the Famous Captain Singleton*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CAwCAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA299&dq=%22send+a+Turk+just+at+the+dusk%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiohY6C0sDQAhVbVWMKHSYmCmwQ6AEILjAE#v=onepage&q=%22send%20a%20Turk%20just%20at%20the%20dusk%22&f=false), first published in 1720. Here's the text where the phrases appear:

> After we had bought several goods, and were preparing to buy several others, the boat being on shore with twelve men, myself, William, the surgeon, and one fourth man, whom we had singled out, we contrived to send a Turk just at the dusk of the evening with a letter to the boatswain, and giving the fellow a charge to run with all possible speed, we stood at a small distance to observe the event. The contentsof the letter were thus written by the old doctor:—
>
> "BOATSWAIN THOMAS,—We are all betrayed. For God's sake make off with the boat, and get on board, or you are all lost. The captain, William the Quaker, and George the reformade are seized and carried away: I am escaped and hid, but cannot stir out; if I do I am a dead man. As soon as you are on board cut or slip, and make sail for your lives. Adieu.—R.S."

I have two questions:

1. Does giving the Turk a charge to run have the same meaning as giving him the duty to run? And could the verb *contrive* involve giving money for something?
2. These four named people were on shore too, so 12 other men were too (16 total)?

Comment: It is not enough just to say *Defoe' s*. You should include the author's complete name & the  work being quoted. You should also enclose the quoted material in 'block quotes'  using the > before each line/paragraph of quoted material. English speakers here assume and can guess, and may even know, which Defoe you're referring to, but that doesn't remove from you the necessity of properly attributing the material.

Comment: Providing a link to an online version is also highly suggested; that way we can check to see if the passage has been quoted properly and/or if there are errors in your source text (not all electronic texts scan or otherwise input without error).

Answer (score 1):

This is 300-year-old language, so there are significant differences in vocabulary and usage.  It also uses nautical language, which is almost a dialect of English in itself.  This is not an easy paragraph for an English learner to understand!

"Give somebody a charge to run" means "Give somebody the order to run".  A charge is a command or instruction.

[Charge](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charge) (definition 4)

> instruction, command

"We contrived to" means "We managed somehow to".  It implies being devious, clever, or tricky.  "My car wouldn't start, but I contrived to recharge the battery from some solar cells."  It has nothing to do with money.

[Contrive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contrive)

> devise, plan
>
> to form or create in an artistic or ingenious manner
>
> to bring about by stratagem or with difficulty

I can't answer your last question without some more context.  It's unclear to me how many people are in which place.

Comment: Great answer except the part at the end.  There are 12 people on board.  Four of us, including me, were on shore shopping.